# Вывод ссылок на дочерние категории внутри Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот такой код для вывода страницы рубрики...
Внутри блока каждой рубрики нужно вывести ссылки на дочерние...

```
<section <? post_class('catalog'); ?>>
    <div class="c-row">
<?
$parent = get_query_var('cat');
$arg = array(
    'parent' => $parent,
    'hide_empty' => 0
);
$all_cat = get_categories($arg);
if($all_cat){
    foreach ($all_cat as $cat){
        $mid = $cat->term_id;
        $cat_img = get_option("category_$mid");
        echo '<div class="c-item -item" style="background-image: url('.$cat_img['cat_bg'].');"><h3 class="-hide">'.$cat->name.'</h3><div class="-show -item"><h3>'.$cat->name.'</h3><p class="c-desc">'.$cat->category_description.'</p><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id).'" class="btn -grey c-link">Смотреть все</a></div><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id).'" class="btn -grey c-link -hide -mhide">Смотреть все</a></div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Каждая рубрика с описанием и фоновым рисунком, вытянутым из произвольного поля рубрики.
Нужно получить ссылки на дочерние рубрики, отображаемых рубрик...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
$mid = $cat->term_id;
```

вставьте

```
$sub_cats = get_categories( array(
    'child_of' => $mid,
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );
if( $sub_cats ){
    foreach( $sub_cats as $sub_cat ){
    // ... ваш код ...
    }
}
```